# How to prevent pycharm jupyter-notebook's markdown cells be triggered into editable form by single click?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ide, markdown

I have pycharm 2023.2.1 (professional edition) on mac. I am working with jupyter notebooks on pycharm. Typically, on standard jupyter notebooks pages (such as hosted by google colab or jupyterlab), only double clikcing a markdown cell will make the cell into editable format. Single clicking the markdown cell won't make it editable. However, in my pycharm, whenver I single click a markdown cell, it will become editable automatically. Even if I press ESC on my keyboard to leave this cell, this cell still stays in the editable raw look. Is there a way to make a markdown cell only editable when I double click it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. It is peculiar that no one anwers.

Comment: I didn't find a solution either so I just switched to VS Code just for handling Jupyter Notebooks and I find it much better in every way now. Turns out Pycharm handling of jupyter notebooks isn't great

Comment: Yeah. PyCharm handling of Jupyter notebooks was even worse years ago. It is now better but I really don't understand why it is just not making these basic features right.

Comment: @Daehan I also switched to VS Code. The VS Code rendering of jupyter  notebooks is a lot better. I don't know why Jetbrains is not noticing this important defect given the popularity of jupyter notebooks nowadays. Years ago VS Code did not seem as popular but now I have seen people everywhere using VS Code for python. Pycharm is just losing the competition.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. The markdown cell just become editable after I run the previous cell (code cell) with shift+enter, which is pretty annoying that we need to execute the markdown cell again. Still unsolve up to now.